# Cauchy-Riemann - physics style

Tags: complex-analysis

I am following the video lectures series by [Prof. V. Balakrishnan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q01b-lV6y5Q) on complex analysis.

He considers a function $f(z) = u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ which is not necessarily analytic. Then lets $\delta h = \epsilon \,e^{i \alpha}$ denote some small distance at an arbitrary angle $\alpha$.

He then goes on to write:

$$ \frac{f(z + \delta h)}{\delta h} = e^{-i \alpha} \bigl (\frac{du}{dx} \cos(\alpha) + i \frac{du}{dy}\sin(\alpha) + i \bigl [ \frac{dv}{dx} \cos(\alpha) + i \frac{dv}{dy} sin(\alpha) \bigr ]\bigr )$$

And argues that the Cauchy-Riemann are satisfied if and only if the above expression is independent of $\alpha$.

The only thing that I can think he must have done is use a sort of "chain rule":

$$ \frac{df}{\delta h} = \frac{df}{dx} \frac{dx}{\delta h} + \frac{df}{dy} \frac{d(iy)}{\delta h}$$

where:

$$ \frac{dx}{\delta h} = \frac{(x + \epsilon cos(\alpha)) - x}{\delta h} = e^{-i\alpha} \cos(\alpha)$$

and:

$$ \frac{d(iy)}{\delta h} = \frac{(iy + \epsilon i \sin(\alpha)) - iy}{\delta h} = e^{-i\alpha} i\sin(\alpha)$$

Can you really do that? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He doesn't write that. But I'm not sure what he does write is correct either. What it should be (or what I'll vouch for, anyway), is $$\frac{f(z+\delta h)-f(z)}{\delta h} = e^{-i\alpha}[\partial_xu\cos\alpha + \partial_yu\sin\alpha +i(\partial_xv\cos\alpha+\partial_yv\sin\alpha)]\\=e^{-i\alpha}[\partial_xu\cos\alpha+i\partial_yv\sin\alpha + i(\partial_xv\cos\alpha-i\partial_yu\sin\alpha)]$$ which we can see is independent of $\alpha$ if $\partial_xu=\partial_y v$ and $\partial_xv=-\partial_y u.$

The numerator is a first order Taylor expansion in $x$ and $y$, of the form $$ f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y) = f(x,y)+ \partial_xf \delta x + \partial_yf\delta y.$$ where you plug in $\delta x=\epsilon\cos\alpha$ and $\delta y=\epsilon \sin\alpha.$